# Return undefined. getStaticProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm working with Next.js, I am trying accessing data but got undefined. Here is my code:

```
function Home({books}) {
 console.log(books)
 return <div>Home</div>
 
}

         export default Home
         
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    let books = await getAllBooks();
 
    return ({
     props: {
         books
     }
 }
    )
 }


 export const getAllBooks = async() => {
    const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/books", {headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:5173/'}});
    if (res.status !== 200) {
        return new Error("Internal Server error");
    }
     const data = await res.data.books;
     return data
    }
```

I am trying to fetch a data and store it in props but when I pass it in javascript component and log, it returns undefined.

Comment: can you add the getAllBooks function to your question?
to see how you implement this

Comment: Yes, I have already added

Comment: it seems ok but you can test the endpoint with postman app
maybe the books is not in your response

Comment: and you don't need to await to this line of code:
const data = await res.data.books;

Comment: In the backend it works perfect. Just dont know and  data stores in props but when use console.log it shows undefined

Comment: can you add console.log before the if in getAllBooks function to see the res compeletly?

Comment: Don't destructure it in function definition like `({books})`. Just do `(props)` and check `console.log(props)`

Comment: here is a log: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/r9s766ipp4derqw/chrome_ur4YMUBZnb.png?dl=0

Comment: have used (props) it returns an empty object

Comment: test it :

let books=[]
try{
 books = await getAllBooks();
}catch(err){
console.error(err)
}

 return {
    props: {
      books,
    },
  };

Comment: Still nothing. Just return undefined. In any case thank for your time.

Comment: are you sure that the home is in the pages folder?

Comment: There's no problem with `({books})`. If `books` is `undefined`, that's fine. It would not cause be the reason *why* it's undefined, however. Take a look at my response, there's a very simple syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

What does your `/pages` folder look like? Do you have a `v1` folder?

You are referencing `"http://localhost:3000/api/v1/books"` so if `v1` does not exist as a folder that would be a problem unless you have some rewrite rules in place.

I used your code in a [test sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/next-js-using-pages-uyk01v) and have no issues.

Comment: The parentheses don't make a difference here.

Comment: Good call! Revising the answer.

Comment: There is no problem with that. I console log books in getStaticProps and everything works, but when I console log books in function home it returns undefined

Comment: There is not enough information to help. Provide more context and information regarding your code - perhaps a *reproducible sandbox*.